# Mudblazor - How to use InputFile on a MudTable?

Tags: .net, blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to add an image upload functionality for each element of a list of objects displayed using `MudTable`. Here's how I tried doing it:

```
<MudTable Items="Data" Dense="true">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Value</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Image</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Delete</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate Context="aa">
        <MudTd DataLabel="Value">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="@aa.Value" For="@(()=>aa.Value)" HelperText="Required" />
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Image">
            <div>
                <MudImage Src="@aa.ImageBase64" Height="50" Width="50" Elevation="25" Class="rounded my-2"></MudImage>
                <InputFile id="fileInput" OnChange="@((e)=> OnFileChange(aa,e))" hidden multiple accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"/>
                <MudButton HtmlTag="label"
                       Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary"
                       StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CloudUpload"
                       for="fileInput">
                    Upload Image
                </MudButton>
            </div>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd>
            <MudIconButton OnClick="@(()=>DeleteAnswer(aa))" Icon="@Icons.Filled.Delete" />
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

The thing with the File Upload implementation of Mudblazor is that it uses a hidden `InputFile` with a specific `id`. So if I placed it on a table, the instance of that `InputFile` will only be valid for the 1st element, so if the Upload Image Button for the 2nd element is clicked, the one being modified will be the 1st element, not the current second element.

I know I should place the `InputFile` outside of the `MudTable` but the thing is, I need to pass the instance of each element on the `OnChange` event of the `InputFile`.
An alternative I was thinking of is to not link the `Upload Image Button` with the `InputFile` but to pass the instance of the current element to a variable when the button is clicked instead. then call the click event of the hidden `InputFile` manually. But I'd like to avoid that so are there any suggestions on how to do this better?

Comment: Simple answer : Place your upload button outside the table.

Comment: not an option @LYass, as per the required UI design. What I did instead was to bring the InputFile component itself outside the table, called the OnClick event of the upload button, since it will be called before the Inputfile-Onchange event, and store the element into a variable, accessible outside the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a `InputFile` for each of your row items in your table. Just be sure to use unique `id` and `for` values:

```cs
<RowTemplate>
  ...
  <MudTd DataLabel="Image">
    <InputFile
      id="@($"file-{context.Id}")"
      OnChange="@(e => this.UploadFiles(e, context))"
      hidden
      multiple />
    <MudFab
      HtmlTag="label"
      Color="@Color.Success"
      Icon="@Icons.Filled.AttachFile"
      Size="@Size.Small"
      for="@($"file-{context.Id}")"/>
  </MudTd>
</RowTemplate>
```

A working demo:

```cs
<MudTable Items="@this.items" Class="mt-5">

  <HeaderContent>
    <MudTh>Id</MudTh>
    <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
    <MudTh>Images</MudTh>
    <MudTh></MudTh>
  </HeaderContent>

  <RowTemplate>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Id">
      @context.Id
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Name">
      @context.Name
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Images">
      @context.Images
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Image">
      <InputFile
        id="@($"file-{context.Id}")"
        OnChange="@(e => this.UploadFiles(e, context))"
        hidden
        multiple />
      <MudFab
        HtmlTag="label"
        Color="@Color.Success"
        Icon="@Icons.Filled.AttachFile"
        Size="@Size.Small"
        for="@($"file-{context.Id}")"/>
    </MudTd>
  </RowTemplate>

</MudTable>

@code {
  private List<Item> items = new();
  private List<IBrowserFile> files = new();

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    this.items = new List<Item>
    {
      new() { Id = "123", Name = "something" },
      new() { Id = "456", Name = "another" }
    };
  }

  private void UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e, Item item)
  {
    item.Images = string.Join(", ", e.GetMultipleFiles().Select(f => f.Name));
  }

  public class Item
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Images { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

[image]

Try online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wumGuBvXQJffyjIA

Comment: that will do the trick indeed, making the id dynamic.